# Web Api Return File with additional data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm returning a file as follows:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string id)
        {
            try
                {
                    GetFileDataResponse retrieveResponse = new GetFileDataResponse();                
                    retrieveResponse = GetFileData(Int32.Parse(id));

                    var folderName = Path.Combine("Resources", "Images");
                    var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);
                    pathToSave = Path.Combine(pathToSave, retrieveResponse.FileUrl);
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(pathToSave);
                    var content = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(pathToSave);
                    new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider()
                        .TryGetContentType(fileName, out string contentType);
                    return File(content, contentType, fileName);

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = ex.ToString();
                return BadRequest() ;
                }
        }
```

Is there a way to send some data additional besides the file?

I want to send some data like "uploadedBy:1", but I don't know if this is possible, I read about some parameter in the content disposition but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Review note: `BadRequest` is for validation errors, i.e. the user didn't give you good inputs. Don't return that from a catch handler. You're lying to the caller. Return a 500 response instead.

Comment: I don't know where this example came from, but it's wrong and it needs to stop. Being unable to trust/use the response code leads to designs that return 200 from everything and indicate error/success with properties of the returned JSON object.

Comment: `I want to send some data like "uploadedBy:1", but I don't know if this is possible,`I;m afraid not,you cannot return File with other data.